# Detect an error and raise flag in Python when running an Matlab script from Python

Tags: python, matlab, error-handling, multiprocessing

I have a Matlab script that I am running it from Python. I want to detect any error happening in my Matlab script and raise a flag in Python (e.g. `e = "error message from Matlab"` and `print(e)`  or  `if error_in_matlab: e=1`). Here is my simplified code to run my `yyy.m` matlab script:

```
import os
path_to_mfile = '/Users/folder/yyy'
matlabCommandStr = 'matlab -nodisplay -r "clear all; close all; run(\'{}\'); quit" '.format(path_to_mfile)

while True:
    try:
        os.system(matlabCommandStr)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        error_flag = 1
        break
```

I know that if I use Matlab toolbox in Python, following code will work:

```
import matlab.engine
while True:
    try:
        eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
        ret = eng.yyy()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        error_flag = 1
        break
```

But I need to work with the command line because of `matlab.engine` limitation and the toolbox that I am preparing is already complicated enough to change to `matlab.engine`, so I want to keep using `os.system(matlabCommandStr)`. I'd appreciate if someone can help with this.

Comment: I recommend that you use the `-batch` option rather than `-nodisplay -r`. You won’t need the `quit` and you won’t need to catch errors. The `clear` and `close` commands are always useless, you are starting a fresh MATLAB session, there is nothing to clear and nothing to close.

Comment: If you use `matlab.engine` you don’t call MATLAB through `os.system`, that’s the whole point. It is also the only way to catch errors and handle them in Python. If you don’t want use the the engine, use the `subprocess` module to launch MATLAB with the `-batch` option, and parse the stderr output. It’s less convenient than the MATLAB engine, but you might get that to work.

Comment: Thanks @CrisLuengo I replaced `-nodisplay -r` with `-batch` and added status to command line code like `status = os.system(matlabCommandStr)` and this helped. When there is no error, it returns 0, and when there is an error `status = 256`. So now I use `256` as my error flag and so far seems it's working. I should start a bigger process to see if this works with the other parts of our pipeline or not. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the hint from @CrisLuengo's answer, I used `-batch` instead of `-nodisplay -r` and then when there is an error `status = 256` and if no error happens then `status = 0`. I used this as a flag to detect errors. The following code helped me to solve this problem:

```
import os
path_to_mfile = '/Users/folder/yyy'
matlabCommandStr = 'matlab -batch "run(\'{}\'); quit" '.format(path_to_mfile)

while True:
    status = os.system(matlabCommandStr)
    if status == 256:
        error_flag = 1
```

I will integrate this into my multiprocess tool. If there were further problems, I'll update here.

Comment: Glad it works! I would use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to launch MATLAB. That way you can capture `stderr` and actually do something with the error message. Also, you don’t need `quit` with `-batch`.